# Convert.ToInt32(nullableVariable) VS nullableVariable.GetValueOrDefault()

Tags: c#, int, nullable

Which of these is the best practice, and how do they work?

```
int? id = null;
Console.WriteLine(id.GetValueOrDefault());
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32(id));
```

Here both return the same value of 0.

Comment: It depends where you want to use it. IMHO, if you want to get `0` if `id` has no value, you should use first option or check by yourself.

Comment: The second expression is in fact calling GetValueOrDefault() because the compiler is using overload resolution - _"if overload resolution chooses a lifted operator then the operand is implicitly converted to the nullable type"_ [source](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/27/nullable-micro-optimization-part-two/). If in doubt, use what seems clearest to you.

Comment: I would say that the second one is better, just because one might try to convert.ToInt32 a nullable of another type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/index)

**The first expression:**

> [GetValueOrDefault()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.getvalueordefault?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Nullable_1_GetValueOrDefault)

Retrieves the value of the current [`Nullable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) object or the default value of the underlying type.

Returns the value of the Value property if the [`HasValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.hasvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Nullable_1_HasValue) property is `true;` otherwise, the default value of the underlying type.

**The second expression:**

> [Nullable types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/using-nullable-types#declaration-and-assignment) (`int? id = null;`)

Nullable types are types that represent all the values of an underlying value type `T`, and an additional [`null`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/null) value.